# Why to choose single threading over multi threading

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu

Why sometimes single threading is faster than multi threading? Is it because of the overhead or something else which i'm not aware of?

I did read many blogs but still confused about the nature of multi threading and how it executes multiple task at the same time

Comment: If you can't come up with a parallel algorithm for a problem you're working on, and it's not useful for your use-case to just run the same program or function for different inputs in parallel, then you're stuck with single-threading.  Basically yes, overhead like inter-thread latency means you need to find parallelism that's coarse enough that threads don't spend all their time stalling on communicating with each other instead of just doing the work without communication overhead.  (Cache misses from different threads accessing the same cache line not all read-only also hurts a lot.)

Comment: And of course it's easier to write single-threaded programs, so often it's a matter of not worth the effort for something that's "fast enough", or just that nobody's done the work yet for that particular program.

Comment: Yeah, your title is backwards.  Choose multithreading when you data is large enough to swamp overhead or where the requirement is split into several mostly-independent tasks.

Comment: @KenWhite and other close voters: that duplicate seems highly specific, not explaining anything general.  I guess the general anti-pattern would be having all the actual work take place inside a critical section, so the work is still serial plus there's locking overhead.  That seems (to me) like an obviously terrible algorithm, and doesn't really answer the question of whether there is a multi-threaded way to get any speed.  (e.g. from larger buffers to amortize locking overhead.  Probably still no unless preparing the data in the buffers takes any time without the lock held.)

Comment: I agree the question's pretty broad and hard to give a specific answer, though, I just don't think that specific duplicate target is a great choice, for people who don't know enough about parallelism to already understand why that would be terrible.